# Can we have extended close comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, close-reasons

Currently when a question gets closed the only thing you see is a standardized close reason. This is pretty bad because sometimes the question comments don't indicate how the close reason fits the question. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170728/can-regex-do-basic-arithmetic), my question got closed as "too broad", but the comments don't indicate why it's too broad.

Can we have a required "extended close reason" field that can be reviewed, allowing reversal of close votes if the extended close reason makes no sense?

Comment: Close voters can always leave a comment, if they feel there's more explanation necessary, or your question is a _borderline_ case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If it was required, I wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: That's merely the same as the futile request for mandatory comments on downvotes. Be happy with the links and hints given in the close vote banner.

Comment: Mandatory: close vote because chsoajcuebwoxucy3h19z774. In any case, it shouldn't be mandatory.... It's the OP's responsibility to figure it out, not the other way around (and not to mention how much it would slow down moderation in general :/ )

Comment: @Patrice In theory it should only slow down moderation if the close reason is bad. Which's precisely what it's meant to do, because if the close reason is bad, maybe the question shouldn't be closed after all...

Comment: @SoniEx2 no, I mean slow down moderation in the sense that on reasons that SHOULD be closed, it'll take more time, for no other reason than the rare occasion where it's wrong.... in which case you go to meta to discuss it :). Better implement for the situation that happens 99% and make THIS more streamlined than optimize for the exception, no?

Comment: @Patrice Hmm... ok...

Answer (score 3):

This already (sort-of) exists: People who vote to close can leave a comment, or choose to use a custom close reason when voting to close ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLwaV.png)), which also generates a comment.

If you believe your question was closed unfairly, there's a few things you can do:

- Edit (and improve !) the question. This will send it to a review queue, where someone will review it, and possibly reopen it.
- Ask for clarification in a comment. If your question was closed by a moderator, or a single user with a gold tag badge, you can @ping them, to ask for clarification. If not, someone else may see your comment, and clarify.
- Ask for clarification here, on Meta.

Before doing these things, read the links in the close message, and make sure that your question is clear, focused, and on-topic.