# Should we require entering a reason on any close vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Currently, the reasons to close questions are very, very broad.

What if it was required to enter a 80 character minimum proposal text on what the asker could do to improve the question and make it valid again? It would allow us to see many, many more well-written questions, as well as having many of to be protected from false closing.

Discuss.

Comment: "It would allow us to see many, many more well-written questions" - That's a false premise. The situation right now is that there are too many questions that *aren't* getting closed and deleted. In fact that are so many of them that it's impossible to find anything that' well-written. If we make it even harder to close questions, it will be putting more hay on the stack while we're trying to find the needle.

Comment: I will be HAPPY to write 80+ chars to explain why I'm closing something.... WHEN new users do their research, check for dupes, follow guidelines, and read the tour. We have a deal?

Comment: Making it harder and more time consuming to close bad questions doesn't allow us to see many more well written questions.  It in fact does the opposite, it results in seeing many, many *less* well written questions because the bad questions aren't being filtered out for them.

Comment: @davidism > instead of <

Comment: @Mysticial You put the bar much to high. questions that are asked by default, are not hight level, for the asker doesn't know of what they do not know.

Comment: @davidism how does that help anyone? you expect some good questions, you make some good reasons. fair as fair.

Comment: @tuskiomi I accept your premise that most questions do not meet a high, or even passable, standard of quality.  Given that premise, why do you want to make it harder to deal with questions that don't meet a high standard of quality?

Comment: @tuskiomi Well the docs ARE there for good reasons. It's YOUR job as OP to look them up. Now, about those "false closes" you talk about... got ANY proof there? Because that's a frequent claim here.... and never proven

Comment: @Servy because 80  characters (<1 minute) is a very small time to spend to improve a question.

Comment: @tuskiomi You *are* getting a good reason whenever a question is closed.  A question *can't* be closed without a reason given.  Forcing people to type out the same reasons over and over again instead of using extremely clear, concise, well thought out descriptions of those reasons only *lowers* the quality of the close reasons people will see.

Comment: @Patrice it seems this post will be a good example in a few minutes....

Comment: @tuskiomi there are NO close votes on your post. Refrain from snark if you want a good meta reception.  Oh, and we CAN put custom close reasons on closure. Most people don't, because the available ones cover the case they are looking at

Comment: @Servy I never suggested to give up suggesting a topic for closure.

Comment: @tuskiomi When many thousands of awful questions are asked every single day, no, that's not a very small amount of time to spend, especially given that an overwhelming majority of those are unsalvageable.  You're talking about spending *hundreds* of *hours* of users' time *every single day* with that argument.  Time that could be spent answering *good* questions,

Comment: @Patrice  haha, While you claim it is 'snark', I see much other bad reception before this! Why is that?

Comment: @Servy It's not often that I see the same people who vote to close also answer questions. SE seems to be devided in this way.

Comment: @tuskiomi at the moment, there are no close-votes on your question. The downvotes indicate [disagreement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) rather than post quality.

Comment: @tuskiomi how is it not snark? Your question has NO close votes right now, and needs 5 to close. So your question is FAR from being closed, yet you already have the mindset it will be wrongfully closed. Show me these "much other bad receptions". This is NOT a good example, as it is not closed

Comment: @tuskiomi I challenge you to support that assertion.  I expect you'll find that users closing lots of questions have all answered *lots* of questions.  I notice that you've only posted *one* answer, and I see *one* question that you've attempted to help someone improve.  For someone who doesn't answer questions or help people to improve them, and who is accusing people who have posted *thousands* of answers of not answering many questions, your assertion simply isn't supported.

Comment: Does this become a *explain down votes* discussion?

Comment: @Servy I cannot support this, for while data on answered questions is publicly available, data on voting to close is not (unless you mean the data that you get when a moderator approves a flag )

Comment: @tuskiomi That's just not true.  Close votes on closed questions are public information.  You can't see close votes on questions that haven't yet attracted enough close votes to be closed, but that wouldn't stop you from supporting your assertion, if it is in fact true.

Comment: In case servy's case fails you might want to check [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=activity). I'm one of the [top close voter and reviewer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)

Comment: @rene where do I find? it seems that i'ts not on your profile, even under the 'all actions' tab

Comment: *coughcough* still waiting for those false closures.....

Comment: I linked you to it @tuskiomi ... don't check my meta profile. I don't close and review much there

Comment: @tuskiomi You seem to be confusing quality with difficulty. And because of that you're claiming that our "bar" is too high. Actually, we don't care whether a question is "low-level" or "high-level", but we do care that questions are well-written and well-researched.

Comment: @patrice try the code golf stack. go to the newest posts, and just look at how many are on hold.

Comment: @tuskiomi code golf closure belongs on their meta (+ I have no clue what their rules are, so I wouldn't be able to judge). Stack examples for Stack meta. And I am asking for SPECIFIC examples. Just like on the main site: The OP does the research. I've seen enough bad posts still opened that warrant closure that I don't believe your assertion to be true. I won't fight to prove it.... I kinda feel that is YOUR responsibility, since this is YOUR discussion....

Comment: @Mysticial I know that easy questions are accepted, as a matter of fact, half of the top-monthly questions show no evidence of time being put into writing or even research. Yet other questions that appear to have the exact same ammount of effort put into them are *closed* for strange reasons.should your question be of the same quality of the top-monthly, it's a crap-shoot as to weather people will close it or not!

Comment: @patrice then I will not fight it, and we can conclude that there are absolutely no wrongly closed posts on SO.

Comment: @tuskiomi okay.... then your discussion is kinda moot, no? half of your proposal is that it helps against false closure. If there are no false closure. PROBLEM SOLVED! (In a less snarky way: I am the first one saying Stack can be rough around the edges and hard to understand for new users... stay enough on meta and you'll see it. But at the same time, I will NOT hunt down statements that I've never seen around the site. If I saw wrongly closed questions often, I'd agree with you. If you can find those examples, I'm happy to change my mindset)

Comment: Here you have [12,146](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/521180?UserId=578411) questions that have been closed by me. Just ping me if you find one that you think  needs to be re-opened.

Comment: @tuskiomi `Yet other questions that appear to have the exact same ammount of effort put into them are closed for strange reasons.should your question be of the same quality of the top-monthly, it's a crap-shoot as to weather people will close it or not!`  Agreed.  There are lots of bad questions that don't manage to get closed because it's too hard to get questions closed.  As a result, bad questions stick around, and cause problems.  Making it much more time consuming to close questions would make that problem *worse*, not better.

Comment: @Patrice except for the fact that some people may not have any clue why their question was closed or how to fix it, even if it *Was* closed rightly.

Comment: @Servy you're saying the top monthly questions are simply questions in which nobody has gotten to closing, yet?

Comment: @tuskiomi There is *lots* of information out there about how to ask a good question, ways of improving questions, and so on.  There's no shortage of information on how someone can fix a bad question, merely a lack of willingness of the author to actually take the time to do so.  Providing even more information won't change that.

Comment: @tuskiomi but that's a different problem altogether. And... close reasons now link to the help center... which in turn links to meta.... that documentation is available and offered with close reasons. If users do NOT review it... how is it our fault?

Comment: @tuskiomi Top monthly by what metric?  If you mean posts with a lot of views,  yes, many of them are low quality.  Popularity and quality are not strongly correlated.

Comment: @Patrice because you have then made the community as a whole worse by confusing someone who probably had a very valid question, simply because they had wording that wasn't appreciated.

Comment: @Servy I meant if you go to http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month. but I have a question, if popularity and quality aren't supported, then why is that even a model of this site? it's like how sony tried to make their own version of VHS, but it failed because the classic VHS, while lower quality, was *more popular*.

Comment: @tuskiomi wait... just to confirm what you mean here..... the "default" close reasons are abrasive and unclear? (and if it was "very valid"... it wouldn't have been closed. But that's another discussion)

Comment: @Patrice Much more so than the Stack-specific reasons, yes.

Comment: @tuskiomi okay... and you think putting the onus on the closers to come with better and less abrasive reasons is a good idea? Again, I'll refer to me saying often that stack is rough around the edges.... People who close-vote a LOT will soon lose their patience in explaining politely, and you'll see even RUDER and MORE abrasive close reasons...

Comment: cross-site duplicate at MSE: [Should a user be forced to add a comment when they vote to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29531/165773)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we have extended close comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327322/can-we-have-extended-close-comments)

Comment: This feature request is almost surely a duplicate. I think I have seen it already at least three times.

Comment: @Patrice there we go.... case and point, your closed question. not off-topic in any way whatsoever, but somehow that's the message that comes across.

Comment: @tuskiomi right... because "does not seek input and discussion" isn't right here? You came here with a conclusion and are unwilling to discuss it, to try and see what might be wrong about your premise. This isn't false closure. This is VERY appropriate closure. When you posted your question it looked as if you were opened to discussion. Now, it's clear you aren't. The closure is appropriate IMHO.  (and it's "case in point", btw :) ). Now, whether you agree or not is different. You can disagree with the closure. That doesn't make it false.

Comment: @Patrice There is a strong line between arguing an opinion, and not discussing it. From my view, I was trying just as hard to convince others as they were trying to convince me. I don't see how in any way that's *not* a discussion.

Comment: @tuskiomi But that doesn't make it "false" closure. You can agree that, to an outside viewer, it's thinkable that you WEREN'T open to discussing? I know I can (I know some of MY messages look as if I wasn't open to discussion as well :P ). The very fact you "knew" this question was going to be closed is, to me, sign enough that while you may have been opened to it, you were more or less "barn shooting", and having already drawn conclusions about this. This isn't conductive to proper discussion imo.

Comment: @Patrice So, if both sides were closed and agruing without faulter, by your description of discussion, There was none from either side. If there was no discussion, then I could not have stated my openness to discuss. Thus I haven't been open nor closed to any side, correct? The fact is, this was closed over a hypocrisy, where other people link I'm wrong, and unable to see their way, yet they are exhibiting just that, while I argue.

Comment: @tuskiomi lol.... see what I mean? I am not even debating whether you were really opened or not here, merely discussing how it APPEARS... and you push back like that. Can you see how it can LOOK to others? Not saying they are right or wrong... but I can see how an outside viewer could see this as non constructive. Anyway, I don't see this going anywhere. Apologies for really trying to help out, I guess.

Answer (score 11):

> Currently, the reasons to close questions are very, very broad.

You want them to be very broad. You want most closed questions to fit in a handful of categories so that people know and understand the valid reasons to close questions.

> What if it was required to enter a 80 character minimum proposal text on what the asker could do to improve the question and make it valid again?

Some people would use that space as intended, and others would pound their keyboard until the close button was enabled. This is not better than the current system, which includes canned close reasons, links to more detailed explanations of the kinds of questions that are on-topic on Stack Overflow, and allows people to leave comments if they want to add specific details tailored to the question they're voting to close.

> It would allow us to see many, many more well-written questions, as well as having many of to be protected from false closing.

Requiring five votes to close and allowing people to reopen questions already protects questions from false closing.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, the reasons to close question are very, very specific about what you can do to improve your question. What part of these close reasons don't you understand?

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

> #### too broad
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. **Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.**

> #### unclear what you're asking
>
> **Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.** As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

There are other close reasons without improvement suggestions (e.g. "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."), but those questions tend to be off-topic no matter the way they are improved.